# Can't recognise Microsoft keyboard and mouse after OS Catalina update

Tags: keyboard, catalina, mouse, microsoft

I updated to the latest OS Catalina 10.15.4 on my MacBook Pro 15 with the Microsoft keyboard and mouse connected and working during the download process.

Once the computer was updated the keyboard didn't work on the computer although I unplugged and plugged the usb bundle.

I have another iMac where there I had the magic keyboard and mouse connected where I also updated it to OS Catalina 10.15.4; as a sanity I plugged the usb of the set to the iMac and it works fine.

I guess I should clear old files/cache of the Microsoft set on my MacBook Pro but cant seem to find a solution to it on the Internet.

I saw this issue: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/intellitype-82-macos-catalina-cannot-install/661f9172-7c04-4839-85e8-1629224b24c2
but prior to the above stated problem I didn't install the intellitype at all.

Would appreciate some help

Comment: Try other USB ports on the MacBook Pro. Try all of them.

Comment: @Allan I tried but it didn't work. eventually I had to restart the NVRAM